# What's the SOQL query for: "Show me Accounts with at least 5 opportunities" and

Tags: soql

What's the SOQL query for: "Show me Accounts with at least 5 opportunities" and more complex: "Show me top 10 Accounts with at least 5 opportunities without Activities in the last 30 days"

Comment: What query did you try so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use aggregate queries to get information for the first question:

`Select AccountId, Account.Name from Opportunity group by AccountId, Account.Name having count(id) >= 5` will give you Accounts with at least 5 opportunities.

The second question can't be done with SOQL. I think it would be possible to do a report with cross filters, though.

Comment: Thanks! That's Great!  For #2,  wondering if we can split it into 2 independent queries and programmatically combine them..hmm

Comment: Yes, you can definitely use Apex to find the accounts. I'd query to get the list of accounts first, then query Activities for those accounts and then remove the ones in both lists.